# Xcode delayed button

Tags: ios

Hello I'm new here and new to app development but I'm building an app with multiple views and I would like to add a button that will go to the next view but the user will have to wait 3 seconds or so on each view before the button is available to be tapped.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a method after a delay with reveals or enables your button,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the info JingJingTao

Answer (score 0):

if you want the delay to happen after button tap then have a look at the below code

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapAction")
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    Your_Button_name.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


    @IBAction func tapAction()
    {
        Your_Button_name.disable=true
        //Delay function to enable your button
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Your_time_value_delay, target: self, selector: Selector("enablefunc"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

// DO SOMETHING WHICH YOU WANT TO DO.....
    }

    func enablefunc()
    {
       Your_Button_name.disable=false
    }
```

Hope this helps. You can modify it based on your requirement....

Comment: Thanks for the info Jobins John